# PHP, MySQL, Crud - "Fetching" mysql data into my update page, displaying data into form field

Tags: php, mysql, crud

Hopefully this makes sense. Been working on a project for awhile and i'm just about done! Just stuck and not sure why this isn't working.

I have an entire Crud app used with php and mysql. Everything works correctly except for when I go to my update.php page. When I click update on the home page, it takes me to the update page where I can fill out fields to update the mysql data. That all works fine! What I am having issues with is when I go to the update page, the form fields are blank. I want them to be pre-filled with the data that's already in there, so "fetching" the data. That way, the user doesn't have to go back and look at the data and then re-type all the information again instead of just backspacing and updating just the field data that they want. Does that make sense? Here's my code. Notice and focus where I have the $fetch variable...I know it's a lot. I tried to remove all the really unecessary stuff. If you are able to look at this and see an easy fix, please let me know! Struggling here. Below is my "update.php" page:

```
<?php 
session_start();

$login_session=$_SESSION['login_user'];?>

<?php

if(!$_SESSION['login_user']){
   header("location: login.php");
   die;
}
?>

<p><a href="javascript:history.back()">Go Back</a> | 
<a href="logout.php"> Logout </a></p>

<?php
include 'scripts/db.php';

if(isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
{
    $id=$_GET['id'];
}

$select=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Order_1 WHERE id='$id'");
$fetch=mysql_fetch_array($select);

if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $product=$_POST['product'];
    $size=$_POST['size'];
    $price=$_POST['price'];
    $shipping=$_POST['shipping'];
    $shipped=$_POST['shipped'];
    $delivered=$_POST['delivered'];

    $update=mysql_query("UPDATE Order_1 SET Name='$name',Product='$product',Size='$size',Price='$price',Shipping='$shipping',Shipped='$shipped',Delivered='$delivered' WHERE id='$id' ");

    if($update) {
    ?>
        <script>alert('Record updated successfully!');</script>
    <?php
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location="home.php";</script>';
    }
    else 
    {
    ?>  
        <script>alert('Error updating record.');</script>
    <?php
    }
    }
?>
<div class="container">

<h1>Edit Your Order and Click Submit:</h1>

<div class="updateForm">
<form method="post">
<p>Name: <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="First, Last" value="<?php echo $fetch['name']; ?>" /></p>
<p>Product: <input type="text" name="product" size="15" placeholder="T-Shirt, Shoes, etc..." value="<?php echo $fetch['product']; ?>" /></p>
<p>Size: <input type="text" name="size" size="10" placeholder="S, M, L, XL, XXL" value="<?php echo $fetch['size']; ?>" /></p>
<p>Price: <input type="text" name="price" size="10" placeholder="$0.00" value="<?php echo $fetch['price']; ?>"  /></p>
<p>Shipping: <input type="text" name="shipping" size="10" placeholder="$0.00" value="<?php echo $fetch['shipping']; ?>" /></p>
<p>Shipped?
Yes<input type="radio" name = "shipped" value="Yes" value= "<?php echo $fetch['Yes']; ?>"/>
No<input type="radio" name = "shipped" value="No" value = "<?php echo $fetch['No']; ?>" /></p>
<p>Delivered?
Yes<input type="radio" name = "delivered" value="Yes" value="<?php echo $fetch['Yes']; ?>" />
No<input type="radio" name = "delivered" value = "<?php echo $fetch['No']; ?>" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="update" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Try replace `mysql_fetch_array` with `mysql_fetch_assoc`

Comment: **WARNING:** When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. DO NOT use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, as it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: He uses old deprecated `mysql_*`, not `mysqli_*`. He should use `mysql_real_escape_string` or (int)/(float) casting to prevent sql-injections.

Also radio inputs marking are made by "checked" attribute, not by value (value is usually 1 or some id for ex.)

Comment: Try to dump what are you getting from the database query, and use mysql_fetch_assoc instead.